# How to merge the two rows with multiple columns into one

Tags: r

[image]

How to clean the above data in R dataframe to

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `dplyr`,

## Data

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  tic = c("FCCY", "FCCY"),
  conm = c("FiveC", "FiveC"),
  Records = c(1,1),
  Fourcent = c(7,NA),
  Fivecent = c(NA,9)
)
   tic  conm Records Fourcent Fivecent
1 FCCY FiveC       1        7       NA
2 FCCY FiveC       1       NA        9
```

## Code

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>%
  group_by(tic, conm) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~unique(na.omit(.x))))

  tic   conm  Records Fourcent Fivecent
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 FCCY  FiveC       1        7        9
```